# Make a full word have more score than a Edge NGram subset

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, n-gram

I'm trying to get an higher score on a document where the full name is matched, instead of the Edge NGram subset with the same value.

So the results are:

```
Pos Name              _score       _id

1   Baritone horn     7.56878     1786
2   Baritone ukulele  7.56878     2313
3   Bari              7.56878     2360
4   Baritone voice    7.56878     1787
```

I intended that the third ("Bari") would have an higher score since it's the full name, however, since the edge ngram decomposition will make all the others to have exactly the "bari" word indexed. So has you can see on the results table, the score is equal for all, and I don't even know how elasticsearch order this, since the _id's are not even sequencial, nor the names ordered.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

### Example 'code'

#### Settings

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "filter": {
      "edgeNGram_filter": {
        "type": "edgeNGram",
        "min_gram": 3,
        "max_gram": 20,
        "token_chars": [
          "letter",
          "digit",
          "punctuation",
          "symbol"
        ]
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "edgeNGram_analyzer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "asciifolding",
          "edgeNGram_filter"
        ]
      },
      "whitespace_analyzer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "asciifolding"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[source](http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams)

#### Mapping:

```
{
  "name": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  },
  "suggest": {
    "type": "completion",
    "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
    "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer",
    "payloads": true
  }
}
```

#### Query:

```
POST /attribute-tree/attribute/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "suggest": "Bari"
    }
  }
}
```

#### Results:

(only left relevant data)

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 7.56878,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "attribute-tree",
        "_type": "attribute",
        "_id": "1786",
        "_score": 7.56878,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Baritone horn",
          "suggest": {
            "input": [
              "Baritone",
              "horn"
            ],
            "output": "Baritone horn"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "attribute-tree",
        "_type": "attribute",
        "_id": "2313",
        "_score": 7.56878,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Baritone ukulele",
          "suggest": {
            "input": [
              "Baritone",
              "ukulele"
            ],
            "output": "Baritone ukulele"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "attribute-tree",
        "_type": "attribute",
        "_id": "2360",
        "_score": 7.56878,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Bari",
          "suggest": {
            "input": [
              "Bari"
            ],
            "output": "Bari"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "attribute-tree",
        "_type": "attribute",
        "_id": "1787",
        "_score": 7.568078,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Baritone voice",
          "suggest": {
            "input": [
              "Baritone",
              "voice"
            ],
            "output": "Baritone voice"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `bool` query operator and its `should` clause to add score to exact matches like this :

```
POST /attribute-tree/attribute/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "suggest": "Bari"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "Bari"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The query in the should clause is called a *signal* clause in the [ElasticSearch definitive guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/controlling-relevance.html?q=relevance), and this is how you can distinguish between perfect matches and ngram ones. You will have all documents that match the must clause, but the documents matching `should` queries will have more score due to the `bool` query scoring formula :

```
score = ("must" queries total score + matching "should" queries total score) / (total number of "must" queries and "should" queries)
```

The result is what you expect, Bari is the first result (far ahead in scoring :) ) :

```
"hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0.4339554,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "attribute-tree",
            "_type": "attribute",
            "_id": "2360",
            "_score": 0.4339554,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Bari",
               "suggest": {
                  "input": [
                     "Bari"
                  ],
                  "output": "Bari"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "attribute-tree",
            "_type": "attribute",
            "_id": "1786",
            "_score": 0.04500804,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Baritone horn",
               "suggest": {
                  "input": [
                     "Baritone",
                     "horn"
                  ],
                  "output": "Baritone horn"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "attribute-tree",
            "_type": "attribute",
            "_id": "2313",
            "_score": 0.04500804,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Baritone ukulele",
               "suggest": {
                  "input": [
                     "Baritone",
                     "ukulele"
                  ],
                  "output": "Baritone ukulele"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
```

Comment: It worked as a charm! +1 for the formula also! thanks